# Pasar variable del controlador a la vista

Tags: php, mvc, poo

Coloco esto como ejemplo de lo que deseo hacer:

```
public function imagenPerfilusuarioController(){

    if(isset($_POST['btnmodimgu'])){


        $respuestaver=Datos::verimagenPerfilusuarioModel($datosController,"usuarios");

 if (isset($respuestaver['img_perfil_usuario'])) {
   $rutaimgv=$respuestaver['img_perfil_usuario'];
   unlink($rutaimgv);
  }


 }
}
```

En esa funcion quiero sacar la variable $rutaimgv, para mostrarla en la vista, como la paso hasta alla?

en la vista llamo dicha funcion de esta manera:

```
  $modificar = new Controller();
  $modificar -> imagenPerfilusuarioController();
```

Comment: La función `imagenPerfilusuarioController` debe retornar el valor esperado, por ejemplo: `return $rutaimgv;`.  Entonces al llamarla desde cualquier parte, obtendrás el valor retornado, por ejemplo: `$resultado_retornado=  $modificar -> imagenPerfilusuarioController();`. Ahora bien, debes mejorar la función para que devuelva algo, o `null`  o `false` o `$rutaimgv`, ya que como la tienes ahora el código no está completamente controlado, por ejemplo si no se cumple la condición `if (isset($respuestaver['img_perfil_usuario'])) {` debería devolver otra cosa que sería controlada en el destino.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba quitando el **unlink $rutaimgv;** y luego haces **return $rutaimgv;** dentro de tu controlador.

Si el modelo retorna los valores correctos a tu controller y la instancia de tu clase es correcta, deberá funcionar pasando la función a una variable y llamandola desde cualquier parte.

```
$modificar = new Controller();
$rutaimgv = $modificar -> imagenPerfilusuarioController();
echo $rutaimgv;
```